# What is an example of a 2 dimensional function where it contains lots of kinks?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

Is there an example of a 2 dimensional function where the functions contains lots of kinks? One such example I thought of that DOESNT have kinks is the Rosenbrock function [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function). However, is there a closed form example where a function has a lots and lots of minima and maxima? Thanks!

Comment: One way is to sum up a bunch of Gaussian functions with different means and small variances. This will give a lot of maxima, not so sure about corresponding minima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example is $$f(x, y) := \cos \pi x \cos \pi y .$$ One can verify readily that

1. $-1 \leq f(x, y) \leq 1$,
2. $f$ has value $(-1)^{k + l}$ (and hence an extremum) at all integer lattice points $(k, l) \in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$, and
3. these extrema are all isolated.